# Pause execution of a method until callback is finished

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency

I am fairly new to Java and extremely new to concurrency. However, I have worked with C# for a while. It doesn't really matter, but for the sake of example, I am trying to pull data off a table on server. I want method to wait until data is completely pulled. In C#, we have async-await pattern which can be used like this:

```
private async Task<List<ToDoItem>> PullItems ()
{
    var newRemoteItems = await (from p in remoteTable select p).ToListAsync();
    return newRemoteItems;
}
```

I am trying to have similar effect in Java. [Here](https://github.com/akshay2000/ProjectMirror-WindowsPhone/blob/master/ProjectMirror/ProjectMirror/MirrorSyncService.cs) is the exact code I'm trying to port (Look inside `SynchronizeAsync` method.)! However, Java Azure SDK works with callbacks. So, I have a few options:

Use `wait` and `notify` pattern. Following code doesn't work since I don't understand what I'm doing.

```
final List<TEntity> newRemoteItems = new ArrayList<TEntity>();
synchronized( this ) {
    remoteTable.where().field("lastSynchronized").gt(currentTimeStamp)
    .execute(new TableQueryCallback<TEntity>() {
          public void onCompleted(List<TEntity> result, 
                                  int count, 
                                  Exception exception,
                                  ServiceFilterResponse response) {
              if (exception == null) {
                  newRemoteItems.clear();
                  for (TEntity item: result) {
                      newRemoteItems.add(item);
                      }
                  }
              } 
          });
}
this.wait();
//DO SOME OTHER STUFF
```

My other option is to move `DO SOME OTHER STUFF` right inside the callback's `if(exception == null)` block. However, this would result in my whole method logic chopped off into the pieces, disturbing the continuous flow. I don't really like this approach.

Now, here are questions:

1. What is recommended way of doing this? I am completing the tutorial on Java concurrency at Oracle. Still, clueless. Almost everywhere I read, it is recommended to use higher level stuff rather than `wait` and `notify`.
2. What is wrong with my `wait` and `notify`?
3. My implementation blocks the main thread and it's considered a bad practice. But what else can I do? I must wait for the server to respond! Also, doesn't C# `await` block the main thread? How is that not a bad thing?

Comment: `this.wait();` in the ui thread blocks the ui thread which you should not do.

Comment: @Raghunandan I am aware of that and I have mentioned it in the question in detail. What option do I have?

Comment: invoke the method once you get the data in the callback.

Comment: @Raghunandan I have mentioned that too! It would disturb flow of method logic. Also, due to lack of proper closures in Java, I can't freely access variables outside the scope of callback. I've edited the question to show what exactly I am trying to port from C# to Java. Code samples are welcome.

Comment: what flow are you talking about. sorry  i don't understand c#. but that is the way you need to do it. You can declare the variables as instance variables initialize in the callback method get the value where you want.

Comment: @Raghunandan It's nothing specific to C#. See the code I linked to in question. `SynchronizeAsync` method has some logic. And if I were to do things inside callbacks, the method will be chopped off. Moreover, I'm doing some server calls inside a loop. How would I rewrite that code in Java?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49859/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-akshay2000)

Comment: maybe use `synchronized` on `newRemoteItems`?

Comment: @gopi1410 I get a crash. The more I think about it, more it seems dumb to block the main thread. So, it boils down to questions 1 and 3.

Comment: first explain what you want to achieve

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov All I want to do is to receive data from server and do some processing. Obviously, I want to server transaction to be complete before I continue with the processing. In my example, `DO SOME OTHER STUFF` is executed even before the callback is finished. I want `DO SOME...` to happen after the callback is finished - just like in C# I can put `await` in front of statement. The next statement won't execute until previous is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either put `DO SOME OTHER STUFF` into callback, or declare a [semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html), and call `semaphore.release` in the callback and call `semaphore.aquire` where you want to wait. Remove synchronized(this) and this.wait.

Comment: I ended up chopping my method off into pieces and established the 'happens after relationship' by moving code inside callbacks. Full code at [Github](https://github.com/akshay2000/ProjectMirror-Android).